Callback attached to runnable runs multiple times
I am coding a backend server in python using lancgain and I need to attach a callback to track each time the chain has been run using track_feedback(). I am using the "callbacks" argument on the with_config() in the self.runnable. But it is getting triggered many times per runnable execution. Could the children chains be somehow inheriting the call?
class BaseInputs(BaseModel):
    """Base inputs model."""
    app: str 
    run_id: str
    score: int
    tool: str
    asset: str

class GA4CallbackHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    def on_chain_start(self, serialized, inputs, **kwargs):
        if not self.has_run:
            print(track_feedback("123456.7654321", 'app', 'tool', 'asset', 'standard', "user", "0").status_code)
            print("feedback_sent")

class FeedbackChain(Chain):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:                
        self.runnable = ( 
            {
                "app" : itemgetter("app"),
                "run_id" : itemgetter("run_id"),
                "score" : itemgetter("score"),
                "tool": itemgetter("tool"),
                "asset": itemgetter("asset")                
            } 

            | RunnableLambda(self.send_feedback)
        ).with_config(run_name="feedback",callbacks=[GA4CallbackHandler()]).with_types(input_type=BaseInputs)

The reults is many triggers of the status code and "feedback_sent" string on console for each feedback sent. I printed the "serialized" parameter and it seems to be executing for each input (so once for "app", another for "run_id"...)
How can I make this execute only once at the start?
I tried using a flag on the handler class but then it only executes once and subsequent executions never run.
I also tried attaching the callback to the RunnableLambda inside the self.runnable chain, that worked but it looks dirty. I'd like it to be attached to the whole chain.
Edit:
The way this is getting executed is with an "add_route".
add_routes(
  app,
  FeedbackChain().get_runnable(),
  enabled_endpoints=["invoke"],
  path=f"/feedback",
  dependencies=[Depends(get_current_active_username)],
)


It sounds like your callback is being triggered for each step in the chain, rather than just once for the entire chain execution. This issue arises because the callback is attached to each individual step in the chain when you use with_config() on the RunnableLambda.
To ensure that the callback is executed only once per chain execution, you can introduce a mechanism to track whether the callback has already been triggered within the same execution context. This can be achieved by maintaining a state flag in the GA4CallbackHandler class.
Here’s a refined approach:

Add a context manager to track the state within each chain execution.
Ensure the callback is only executed once by checking the state before proceeding with the callback logic.

Here is how you can do it:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Any, Dict
from operator import itemgetter
from some_library import RunnableLambda, Chain, BaseCallbackHandler  # Adjust import as per your library

class BaseInputs(BaseModel):
    """Base inputs model."""
    app: str 
    run_id: str
    score: int
    tool: str
    asset: str

class GA4CallbackHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    has_run = False

    def on_chain_start(self, serialized: Dict[str, Any], inputs: Dict[str, Any], **kwargs: Any):
        if not self.has_run:
            self.has_run = True
            print(track_feedback("123456.7654321", 'app', 'tool', 'asset', 'standard', "user", "0").status_code)
            print("feedback_sent")
    
    def reset(self):
        self.has_run = False

class FeedbackChain(Chain):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.callback_handler = GA4CallbackHandler()
        self.runnable = ( 
            {
                "app": itemgetter("app"),
                "run_id": itemgetter("run_id"),
                "score": itemgetter("score"),
                "tool": itemgetter("tool"),
                "asset": itemgetter("asset")                
            }
            | RunnableLambda(self.send_feedback)
        ).with_config(run_name="feedback", callbacks=[self.callback_handler]).with_types(input_type=BaseInputs)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.callback_handler.reset()
            return self.runnable(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            self.callback_handler.reset()

    def send_feedback(self, inputs: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        # Your feedback sending logic here
        pass

# Example usage:
feedback_chain = FeedbackChain()
feedback_chain.run({"app": "example_app", "run_id": "1234", "score": 90, "tool": "example_tool", "asset": "example_asset"})

Explanation:

GA4CallbackHandler:

Introduces a has_run flag to track if the callback has been executed.
Implements on_chain_start to execute the callback logic only if has_run is False.
Adds a reset method to reset the has_run flag, ensuring the callback can be triggered in subsequent executions.


FeedbackChain:

Initializes the GA4CallbackHandler.
Resets the handler before and after running the chain to ensure proper state management.



This approach ensures that your callback logic within on_chain_start is executed only once per chain execution, regardless of the number of steps in the chain.

Thanks for the answer. This is not working because the "run" function is not getting executed. I tried "stream" and "invoke" but they are not being executed either. I added context explaining where this cplass is instantiated, do you know which method "add_routes" would execute on the class? If I found out I could do a similar solution to what you propose.

Change the on_chain_start function as:
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.executions = set()

def on_chain_start(self, serialized, inputs, **kwargs):
    run_id = inputs.get('run_id')
    if run_id not in self.executions:
        self.executions.add(run_id)
        print(track_feedback("123456.7654321", 'app', 'tool', 'asset', 'standard', "user", "0").status_code)
        print("feedback_sent")


Since the GA4CallbackHandler is only instantiated once the run_id is always the same, so this doesn't work.
